# C++ Creating Atan2 from Atan

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry, atan2

How would i go about taking my `atan` function and make it into `atan2`?
For example

```
float myAtan2(double a, double b)
{
    float atan2val = //calculate atan2 using atan
    return atan2val;
}
```

Sorry I'm not the best at trigonometry!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: Haha, I was about to post that, user4581301. If you already have an atan function the solution to this is trivial.

Comment: @RobertM. that is why i posted this question, i know it can easily be done using atan but i am not good at trigonometry.

Comment: I was under the impression that you already had an atan function. No?

Comment: @RobertM. i already have an Atan functon. But can't figure out how to calculate Atan2 with it. Like i said i suck at trig

Comment: If you have a functional atan, Just use the linked formulas and a few if statements to handle the six cases. It's a solved problem. No trig required.

Comment: @coddding Why do you need to know anything about trig? The Wiki shows the logic, you just have to translate that into code. Any programmer should be able to do it without knowing what the `atan` function does.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, could you click it as accepted please?

Comment: @RobertM. no problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
float myAtan2(double a, double b)
{
    float atan2val;
    if (b > 0) {
        atan2val = atan(a/b);
    }
    else if ((b < 0) && (a >= 0) {
        atan2val = atan(a/b) + pi;
    }
    else if ((b < 0) && (a < 0) {
        atan2val = atan(a/b) - pi;
    }
    else if ((b = 0) && (a > 0)) {
        atan2val = pi / 2;
    }
    else if ((b = 0) && (a < 0)) {
        atan2val = 0 - (p / 2 );
    }
    else if ((b = 0) && (a = 0)) {
        atan2val = 1000;               //represents undefined
    }
    return atan2val;
}
```

You can probably code it prettier, but that's the logic, which I got from here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation.

I'm returning 1000 (an impossible value for an arctan) to represent "undefined". You could do it some other way maybe by using NaN or something.

Comment: Reasonable answer, but it's too cut-n-pastable. You have to be a bit careful with trivial problems. You do not want to find yourself working with someone who graduated with a diploma in Cargo Cult Programming.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm 14 lol, don't worry this isn't for a class or "graduated with a diploma" or whatever lol. This is just for a little program i am working on for fun, nothing else.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not sure I understand the criticism. The solution is reasonable and works but... it can be cut and pasted? I'm not sure I see the problem. 

By the way I graduated with a BS in Computer Engineering but that was back when "embedded systems" seemed like an exciting new thing.

Comment: I've gotten less judgmental over the years. At the time I would have been expecting more explanation, and my worry was people would simply copy the answer and use it without understanding why it worked. Today I'm looking at it more from the point of view that anyone who wanted to know how this worked would have already looked up the math, and if they still had problems, this bit of code would answer them pretty fast, explanation or no.

Comment: And October-December 2016 I was busily re-writing pretty much everything written by a former co-worker and trying to institute a code review policy so we never got into the same mess ever again.